# Access (VSFTP) FTP server from mobile networks

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

**Setup:**

FTP server using `vsftpd` with passive mode enabled along with a `10000-40000` ports opened in the firewall and ec2 security rules.

**Problem:**

Cellphones networks internet (`2/3/4G`) can’t access the FTP server, no response received. Everything works just fine on fixed line connections like fiber internet and broadband connections.

Please help, I need the FTP server to be accessible from everywhere.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Can't access the server at all from cellphone internet or non-static IP internet clients.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: can they access other ftp services such as ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/ ?

can other internet devices out of your lan, access your ftp?